# Django multiple many to many and post_save processing

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-signals

I have a model that contains multiple many to many fields:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Topic(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Article(models.Model):
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author, related_name='articles')
    topics = models.ManyToManyField(Topic, related_name='articles')
```

I need something pretty simple:

A method to be executed after the article is saved where I can access both authors and topics of that instance.

My first attempt has been with a `post_save` signal, but the signal is fired when the model itself is saved, not after its relationships are saved, which come from a through model obviously.

After some online reading I realized that I probably need to create my own signal and connect to it. The problem is that I have no idea what to overwrite and where to fire that signal.

Since I need this on multiple models, I thought I could create some `M2MPostSaveModel` class and have my models inherit it so I can just catch the signals..

But where does Django sends the signals? How can I overwrite it? I honestly have no idea and I had no luck searching in the docs, so apologies if it was there already and I didn't see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally did it, here's how:
I created a new signal

```
import django.dispatch
m2m_post_save = django.dispatch.Signal(providing_args=["instance"])
```

Then I created a subclass of the ModelAdmin class that fires it after it finishes saving the related elements:

```
class M2MPostSaveModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):

    def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
        super(M2MPostSaveModelAdmin, self).save_related(request, form, formsets, change)
        m2m_post_save.send(sender=self.__class__, instance=form.instance)
```

Now all I have to do is to subclass my ModelAdmin class with my M2MPostSaveModelAdmin class and hook up the signal to my method.

```
def doo_something_with_updated_instance(instance, **kwargs):
    # Here your instance has all the m2m relationships updated

m2m_post_save.connect(doo_something_with_updated_instance sender=YourModelAdminClass)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `m2m_changed` for separate processing.

```
def topics_changed(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # Do something

m2m_changed.connect(topics_changed, sender=Article.topics.through)
```

so do with `authors` also

Comment: I thought about that, but I have 2 problems with this solution:

1) my code involves both informations (I need to send an email with the full article, authors and topics). I can make them mutually call each other and only execute the 'logging' part once they're both done but that's very gimmicky and not readable.

2) I'd much rather have a single superclass that overrides this behavior with a custom signal so I won't have to write this code more than once. I have other models for which I need this behavior, so having a superclass that handles a `m2m_post_save_signal` is much preferable.

Comment: @XelharK What is that ?

Comment: what if you check both got filled then send mail with full article

Comment: You may need to change your model.. unless .. it's not possible

Comment: How should I change my models?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95304/discussion-between-raja-simon-and-xelhark).